# How do I load textures directly into a MTLTexture of type MTLTextureType.type2DArray? How do I load a Metal texture 'array?'

Tags: swift, textures, metal

I have a for loop, where I iterate and load each texture into an array of `[MTLTexture?]`. However, now it's just one `MTLTexture` whose type is set to `MTLTextureType.type2DArray`. What's the cleanest way to load textures from files into this texture 'array?'

Answer (score 0):

Create the texture2d_array, then loop and load the individual array slice data with [replace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture/1515679-replace), where ***slice*** is your array index. That's the way to do things so that Metal (or any other graphics API in fact) can apply certain optimisations to the memory layout, for example. On GPU, texture data is usually stored different than plain data so that common operations such as sampling are quicker.

Comment: But how do I `replace` each slice with the contents of a PNG file efficiently?